# Calculating a value from a different column and a different row using PETL

Tags: python, etl, petl

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------------+------+-----------+
| EffectiveDate | TSV  | MTDReturn |
+===============+======+===========+
| '1994-01-30'  |  100 |      0.04 |
+---------------+------+-----------+
| '1995-02-28'  | None |      0.02 |
+---------------+------+-----------+
| '1992-03-31'  | None |      0.01 |
+---------------+------+-----------+
| '1974-08-30'  | None |      0.06 |
+---------------+------+-----------+
```

I'm using the `PETL` library to try and populate the `TSV` value. I'm able to do this by breaking the table down into a list of dicts and manipulating it, but I was asked to do it using `PETL` only.

The formula is pretty straight forward: `TSV = previousTSV * (1 + MTDReturn)`

I have looked into `aggregation` but there's nothing to group them by.

Perhaps I could join a table that has a column with `previousTSV`?

Comment: Would you include your source code and some input data (if it's large use github) so we can have a tinker please?

Comment: @Splatmistro: question should be minimal, complete & verifiable, links aren't helpful

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good fit for [addfieldusingcontext](https://petl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/transform.html#petl.transform.basics.addfieldusingcontext).  This will add the column value using a function which receives the previous row, (None for first row).  I'm guessing you would use something like:

```
def calculate_tsv(prv, cur, nxt):
    if prv is not None:
        return prv.TSV * (1 + cur.MTDReturn)

etl.addfieldusingcontext(table1, 'TSV', calculate_tsv)
```